# Nightly syncing of TFS to SVN

Tags: svn, tfs

Our development department is going to be using Team Foundation Server for our projects, but we're required to sync up with the company standard SVN server on a nightly basis.  Is there any good method to sync them up (TFS to SVN), like a nightly scheduled task that runs an SVN add, remove and commit?

Comment: I would just use SVN. That just sounds like unnecessary complexity.

Comment: Yes, why are you using TFS for vcs if you already have version control you are required to use?  That sounds like additional problems (tfs --> svn and then also svn ->> tfs)

Answer (score 4):

Have you looked at [tfs2svn](http://sourceforge.net/projects/tfs2svn/) ?

There is also the [SvnBridge](http://www.codeplex.com/SvnBridge) project. I guess you could use svnsync against SvnBridge but I haven't tried.

Answer (score 1):

You could try [svnbridge](http://www.codeplex.com/SvnBridge)

Answer (score 0):

Yeah I've looked at tfs2svn and that appears to go the other way, using SVN primarily and storing it in a TFS repository.  What I'm looking for is a method to work primarily in TFS, and push to a SVN repository.

Comment: The project description on TFS2svn seems to suggest that it goes the other direction - TFS -> SVN. Is this not the case?

Answer (score 0):

Would it be possible for you to just use a build task on TFS to "Get Latest" every night to a particular network location, and then have another task that commits that to the central repository?

Even better, could you set up something that does the same thing on every check-in to TFS? That way, you could make sure that both repositories have the same VC history, whereas the solution you suggest (and my first one) only give you version history correct to the day, not the check-in.